# How to use an external swf as a preloader in Flash

Tags: flash, external, preloader

I have a project where I want to use different pre-loaders from time to time so I wanted to know if there was a way I could have my project use an external swf for the pre-loader  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, and in fact that's a very common practice.

Your external preloader file just has to instantiate an instance of the Loader class, then load in your payload .swf. While the payload is loading in, you can listen for ProgressEvent.PROGRESS and use that to update some sort of a load bar or whatever. It would look something like this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Preloader extends MovieClip
    {
        // this loads in your main swf
        public var loader:Loader;

        // this points to the location of your main swf
        public var request:URLRequest;

        // this holds a reference to your main swf once it's been loaded in.
        public var content:MovieClip;

        public function Preloader()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler);

            super();
        }

        // it's a good practice to wait for ADDED_TO_STAGE before you start doing stuff, that way you can avoid certain Null Reference Errors
        protected function addedHandler(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler);

            loader = new Loader();
            request = new URLRequest("path/to/your/file.swf");

            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        }

        // This will fire when your main swf is loaded in.
        protected function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

            trace("Load completed! Now we're going to add the target swf to the timeline:");

            content = MovieClip(loader.content);

            /*
             *      Additional logic can go here to remove your loadbar or etc.
             */ 

        }

        // this will fire if there's a problem with loading in the swf
        protected function errorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("Error: the path specified was incorrect. Unable to find that file. Here's the error in full:\n " + e)
        }


        // this will fire constantly while the target swf is being loaded, so you can see how much more you have to load.
        protected function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            var perLoaded:Number = 100* (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal)
            trace("Percent Loaded: " + perLoaded);

            /*
            *   Additional logic can go here to update your load bar, etc.
            */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach I'm going to need. the flash project I have already has a loader in it that spins until a bunch of other stuff loads then it goes to the next frame where the preloader nolonger exists or exists but stops. so I just want to load an external aminmation until and make the animation stop or disappear when everything else is loaded

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a bit more complicated - you could use some sort of a factory pattern to generate your loader class on the fly, I guess, but even then I'm not sure if that would work if you're doing the frame1/frame2 export trick.  Short answer: it's possible, but may taking some doing depending on the way your project is set up.